# Why the sphere spectrum is more correct than $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-category, chromatic-homotopy

One may argue that $\mathbb{S}$ is more correct than $\mathbb{Z}$. Can anyone make it more explicitly? For example, what information will be lost if we work in $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{S}$？

Chromatic homotopy theory may give a partial answer. I know that by chromatic homotopy theory, the sphere spectrum has more information than integer which is known as $v_n$ self map. It turns out that sphere spectrum has infinity Krull dimension. But I am a beginner of chromatic homotopy theory so I cannot tell the whole and true story. Any explanation of the advantages of $\mathbb{S}$ by chromatic homotopy theory will be appreicated.

BTW, There is a joke on the internet, shown in the picture.[image]

Comment: What is your precise question ? Make what more explicit ?

Comment: A *joke*?  On the *Internet*?  I'm not sure I believe that.

Comment: Integers only have primes $p$. The sphere spectrum has primes "$p$", "really $p$", "really really $p$", "really really really $p$", ..., and "$p$ by any means".

Comment: @LSpice Next he'll saying he's found pornography on the internet!

Comment: We don't know how to efficiently factor large integers, yet someone claims that the sphere spectrum is 'more correct' than the integers, huh?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Can you explain (or point to an explanation of) what this thing about being “$p$”, “really $p$”, etc. means, to someone who just knows the definition of a spectrum?

Comment: The comic says "natural numbers" ($\mathbb{N}$) and not "integers" ($\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen : some keywords would be "Morava K-theory", "chromatic homotopy theory", 'Balmer spectrum", "thick subcategory theorem". Basically the idea is that while to study an abelian group, the base tool you have is to study it "one prime at a time", to study a spectrum you can first do that for ordinary primes, but then you have, for every $p$, a whole new hierarchy of localizations you can perform, organized in "chromatic heights". You can call these "new primes".

Answer (score 17):

For this to work, it is best to identify connective spectrum with spaces equipped with a group-like $E_\infty$-algebra structure (these are equivalent).

From this point of view:

- $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free abelian group on one generator.
- The sphere spectrum $\mathbb{S}$ is the free group-like $E_{\infty}$-space on one generator.

Similarly:

- $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial ring, so the initial 0-truncated (connective) ring spectrum.
- $\mathbb{S}$ is the initial (connective) ring spectrum.

So, if you (like many people working in homotopy theory and/or higher category theory and/or homotopy type theory) think that spaces are the real fundamental objects and sets are just the reflective subcategories of 0-truncated space, then the role usually played by $\mathbb{Z}$ in traditional set-based mathematics is now played by $\mathbb{S}$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ only appear as the $0$-truncation of $\mathbb{S}$.

For example, some people have argued that one way to do algebra and geometry "below Spec $\mathbb{Z}$" (in the spirit of "the field with one element") was to do algebra and geometry over the sphere spectrum (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.10801) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.08820) for an example of this - but this is a fairly common idea)

Comment: What do you mean by group-like? Just that the additive structure has (homotopy) subtraction or something more than that?

Comment: For $E_\infty$-algebra group-like mean "every element has an inverse", but it is enough to ask that the $\pi_0$ is a group, no higher coherence condition are needed thanks to the uniqueness of inverse (or rather all the higher conditions you may want to ask - like the existence of a map giving the inverse of an element, the existence of map specifying the homotopy $x^{-1} x = 1$, etc... will automatically be present for bifibrant objects).

Comment: I have update the question. I wonder what kind of information will be lost if we work in $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{S}$.

Comment: I really want to answer: the stable homotopy groups of sphere, but that would really fail to do justice to what is really going on. Doing arithmetic or algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{S}$ is really much much more rich and complicated than over $\mathbb{Z}$ (which is already very rich and complicated), so much so that most of it isn't fully understood yet. So, a lot is lost in many different directions, and people can probably give you a lot of examples, but probably not a general picture.

Comment: In the early days of Waldhausen's work on algebraic $K$-theory, this idea was already present. In that context, the spectrum $A(X)$ for a based space $X\sim BG$ can be regarded as the $K$-theory spectrum of the group ring $S[G]$. This is much better than the $K$-theory of $\mathbb Z[\pi_0(G)]$, in that it "knows more" about geometric questions regarding $X$.

Comment: This and other things (one example, related to $K$-theory, is Topological Hochschild Homology) led to the idea that "doing algebra" with $S$ rather than $\mathbb Z$ as the universal or ground ring was worthwhile.

Answer (score 15):

An elementary answer to the first part of your question: Finite sets are more fundamental than their cardinalities.

Consider the category of finite sets and bijective functions.  Its geometric realization (= nerve, or classifying space) has the homotopy type of $\coprod_{n\ge0} B\Sigma_n$.  Forgetting the choices of bijective functions, and only remembering their existence, gives a map to the set $\mathbb{N}_0 = \{n \ge 0\}$ of non-negative integers.  This way the symmetries of a finite set are disregarded: you can either fix or transpose the two elements in $\{a, b\}$, whereas the number $2$ does not intrinsically come with such structure.

Soon you want to add and multiply finite sets, using disjoint union and cartesian product, and these operations on $\coprod_{n\ge0} B\Sigma_n$ induce the usual sum and product in $\mathbb{N}_0$.  We now have a map of semirings.

Shortly thereafter you want to solve equations, and need to subtract.  For this, you need to ring complete the addition in $\coprod_{n\ge0} B\Sigma_n$, while preserving the multiplication (see Remark A), and the resulting ring space has the homotopy type of $\text{colim}_k \, \Omega^k S^k = \Omega^\infty \mathbb{S}$, with the ring space structure coming from the ring spectrum $\mathbb{S}$, the sphere spectrum.  This now maps to the ring completion of $\mathbb{N}_0$, namely the integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

The first thing that is lost under $\mathbb{S} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the image of the transposition of $a$ and $b$, i.e., the Mobius strip/line bundle over the circle, which corresponds to the loop in $\Omega^2 S^2$ given by the Hopf fibration $\eta \colon S^3 \to S^2$.

Remark A: One way to resolve the caveat raised in

```
Thomason, R. W.
Beware the phony multiplication on Quillen's A−1A.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 80 (1980), no. 4, 569–573.
```

is given in

```
Baas, Nils A.; Dundas, Bjørn Ian; Richter, Birgit; Rognes, John
Ring completion of rig categories.
J. Reine Angew. Math. 674 (2013), 43–80.
```